# Ansible ERROR! 'retries' is not a valid attribute for a TaskInclude

Tags: ansible, ps, retry-logic, until-loop

My requirement is to run the script `stop-all` as many times (5 retries) until the output of `ps -fu user1 |wc -l` becomes less than 2.

I wrote the below ansible playbook for the same:

```
cat stop.yml

  - hosts: dest_nodes
    tasks:
      - name: Start service
        include_tasks: "{{ playbook-dir }}/inner.yml"
        retries: 5
        delay: 4
        until: stopprocesscount.stdout is version('2', '<')


cat inner.yml

      - name: Start service
          shell: ~/stop-all
          register: stopprocess

      - name: Start service
          shell: ps -fu user1 |wc -l
          register: stopprocesscount
```

However, I get the below error running the playbook.

```
ERROR! 'retries' is not a valid attribute for a TaskInclude

The error appears to be in '/app/playbook/stop.yml': line 19, column 9, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


      - name: Start service
        ^ here
```

Can you please suggest?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, correct the indentation of tasks in `inner.yml`. Secondly, remove `retries`, `delay` and `until` from `stop.yml` and move them to specific task as these are task level parameters.

Since you need to retry one task based on another task, you can just combine the script and command and extract the result of wc -l command like below:

Since stdout_lines will contain list of strings and version requires int hence the conversion.

*inner.yml*

```
  - name: Start service
    shell: ~/stop-all; ps -fu user1 | wc -l
    register: stopprocesscount
    retries: 5
    delay: 4
    until: stopprocesscount.stdout_lines[stopprocesscount.stdout_lines | length - 1] | int  is version('2', '<')
```

*stop.yml*

```
  - hosts: dest_nodes
    tasks:
      - name: Start service
        include_tasks: "{{ playbook-dir }}/inner.yml"
```

Comment: correcting the inner.yml does not solve the problem. I continue to get the same error.

Comment: Added the full solution

Comment: thank you, I will test this solution in the next 4 hours and accept the answer if it works.

Answer (score 0):

**Not all task attributes work with all task** (here TaskInclude task).

There is no clear documentation, such a compatibility matrix, but the error message here is quite clear "is not a valid attribute".

By instance:

You cant loop a Block: `'with_items' is not a valid attribute for a Block`

You cant async a TaskInclude, see https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/57051.